# df in polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, analysis, differential-geometry

Let M be smooth manifold $M$={$(x,y) \in R^2 : x>0$} and $f$ be smooth function, $f: M \rightarrow R$, $f(x,y)=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$. Compute coordinate representation for $df$, use polar coordinates.

My solution:

Let $(M,\varphi)$ be a chart on $M$, $(r,\theta)=\varphi(x,y)=(\sqrt{x^2+y^2},arctan(\frac{y}{x}))$, then $\varphi^{-1}(r,\theta)=(rcos(\theta),rsin(\theta))$.

Coordinate representation of $f$ is $f \circ \varphi^{-1}(r,\theta)=\frac{1}{r}$.

So $df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}dr+\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}d\theta=-\frac{1}{r^2}dr$

Is it correct?

Comment: $\frac{\cos\theta}{r}$ not $\frac{1}{r}$.

Answer (score 2):

> Coordinate representation of $f$ is $f∘\varphi^{−1}(r,θ) = 1/r$.

You were doing fine up until here -- how do you get this by substituting the calculated values of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: thank you, I put $r$ instead $rcos\theta$ in numerator by mistake